# Jacobian elliptic functions regarded as functions of the modulus.

Tags: calculus, elliptic-functions

Could anyone provide any references where the properties of Jacobian elliptic functions (and their derivatives) regarded as functions of the modulus are discussed? Especially it would be interesting to find out how to take the first order partial derivative of $cn (u, k)$ with respect to the modulus $k$.

Comment: Does this help? http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/JacobiCN/20/01/02/. And there are formulas in Byrd/Friedman 710.50ff

Comment: Yes, it does, but I would really like to know how to derive the derivatives though.

Comment: I found a way to take first order derivative in a book by Derek F. Lawden ["Elliptic Functions and Applications"](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Q0T2BwAAQBAJ&dq=inauthor:%22Derek+F.+Lawden%22&source=gbs_navlinks_s)